# Which application causes to invoke MDM.exe(Machine Debug Manager)?? How can I disable it?

Tags: windows-7, process

Everytime I start-up my PC(Windows 7 x64) the **MDM.exe** is listed under "Processes" tab of Task manager... Located in ***C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MDM.EXE***

Unless there is a bug, no need for debugging.. 
[image]

**Q1**.What's the need for this official Microsoft's machine debug manager?
**Q2**.If MDM is invoked then how to find what invoked it? and why?
**Q3**.How can I completely disable it so that it can't be launched up? and thus no need to go to task manager to end this process manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to help troubleshoot scripting errors in Internet Explorer. It can be disabled by doing the following;

1. Open IE.
2. Click Tools.
3. Select Internet Options.
4. Click the Advanced tab.
5. Select the Disable script debugging check box.
6. Click OK.

[image]