# mdm.exe using up my cpu and and gpu making the computer hot, what should I do?

Tags: gpu, overheating

How do I remove the background process mdm.exe, which is using my CPU and GPU in the background?

When I open Task Manager I see a mdm.exe task which uses ~15% of CPU power. Please tell me what to. It would be great to get step by step instructions.

Comment: Similar question:: https://superuser.com/q/775236/

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/775241/760480 This should contain the answer.